# How can access to a private variable in another class by using a getter function?

Tags: java, getter-setter

**First class(The parent class)**

```
package revisionOOP;
public class Myclass {
    private int x;
    public void changeThis() {
        x = 10;
        System.out.println("x = " + x);
    }
    //getter
    public int UnprivateX() {
        return this.x;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Myclass inst = new Myclass();
        inst.changeThis();
    }
}
```

**The other class(The child class)**

```
package revisionOOP;
public class MySecondClass extends Myclass {
    static int y;
    public void changeExThis() {
        y = 20;
        System.out.println("x = " + inst.UnprivateX());
        //I want to get the private x value from Myclass class  ,How ?
        System.out.println("y = " + y);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MySecondClass inst = new MySecondClass();
        Myclass inst2 = new Myclass();
        inst2.changeThis();
        inst.changeThis();
        inst.changeExThis();
    }
}
```

How can access to a private variable in another class by using a getter function ?
And how can i change it in the child class ?

Comment: You should not have instance of MyClass. Your instance: "inst" has acces to methods MyClass

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The method UnprivateX gives you access to x. By the way the standard name is getX. You don't need an instance of MyClass because MySecondClass inherits MyClass. You can simply call UnprivateX to get the value of X.

Comment: And if you wanted to be able to _change_ the value of `x` from outside of `MyClass`, you'd need to add a `public` method into `MyClass` that would  provide that functionality.

Comment: Yeah i noticed ! Thank you men @KevinAnderson !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use method in child like this

```
public void changeExThis() {
    y = 20;
    System.out.println("x = " + UnprivateX());
    System.out.println("y = " + y);
}
```

Also you can use
`this.UnprivateX()` or `super.UnprivateX()`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should declare all fields of class as private, then create getters and setters for each one and they have to have names start with getFieldName & setFieldName. and should be public.

Comment: You can help OP with some sample code instead of just writing the solution.

Comment: Why all field as private ? Can i just declare one private and the other public ,What's the deal on that ?

Comment: Ofcourse you are able to declare some fields as public, but it is very bad practice to do it in this way. If you want to write a clear code in the future you should follow simple rules of encapsulation - keep all fields private.